# How do I replace words that contain no letters at the beginning of my string?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I want to replace words at the beginning of my string that contain no letters with nothing.  A "word"  is any sequence of characters that is surrounded by a space (or the beginning or end of the line).  So for example, this string

```
   123  255 abc
```

would become

```
abc
```

while this string

```
1556  2a2  ccc
```

would become

```
2a2 ccc
```

I have tried

```
string.gsub(/\A[[:space:]]*[^\p{L}]+/, '')
```

but this isn't getting it done.  How can I replace all words that don't contain letters at the beginning of my string?

Comment: You question is poorly worded. In Ruby a "word" is a string that contains *work characters* (letters, digits and underscores". "Words that contain no letters" are therefore strings of underscores, which I'm sure is not what you meant. Instead of "word" use, say, "substring".

Comment: What is "no letters with nothing"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll likely need a word boundary (`\b`) and anchors (instead of the `\A`).
This works as expected:

```
^[[:space:]]*[^\p{L}]+\b
```

See [**a demo on rubular.com**](http://rubular.com/r/oo20lWl8jo).

---

As noted by @Cary in the comments, you can even simplify your expression to
`\A[^\p{L}]+\` (alternatively: `^[^\p{L}]+\` for every line start).

Comment: @Cary's improvement `^[^p{L}]+ will transform `123 25a5` to `a5`. Which is **wrong**. Essential to any correct regex-based answer is that you match either the word boundary at the start of the first correct substring, or the space inbetween a incorrect and a correct substring. Both yours and my answer comply.

Comment: @MarcLambrichs: No, the problem is not the expression itself but SO which makes the **space in the end** invisible, see http://rubular.com/r/SX9JLItjWN for his expression in action.

Answer (score 1):

This will:

```
string.gsub(/^[^a-zA-Z]+\s/, '')
```

or (if you want to match unicode chars):

```
string.gsub(/^[^\p{L}]+\s/, '')
```

check it out at [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/bd8ud0shaE)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split` to split your string into words and `drop_while` to filter the first words on a regex:

```
> '   123  255 abc'.split().drop_while { |e| e=~/^\d+$/ }.join(' ')
=> "abc"
> '1556  2a2  ccc'.split().drop_while { |e| e=~/^\d+$/ }.join(' ')
=> "2a2 ccc"
```